# コレ meaning in this sentence

Tags: meaning

> 長さ的には丁度いい。
>   しなりもなんとか。
>   ……こういう“強化”は初めてだ。
>   けど原理は間違っていないと思う。
>   要は補強に補強を重ねて、きちんとしたモノに仕上げればいいだけの話。
>   **それにコレだったら、あいつが持ってたから参考になる。**
>   くわえて、魔力ならさっきから体に流れっぱなしだ。
>   あとはいつもの工程を繰り返せばいい。
>
> As for the lenght, it's perfect.
>   Regarding the elasticity, I will make it do.
>   This type of "strenghtening", is the first time I do it.
>   I think I have the basics down though. *(Lit. But the basics, I do not think they are wrong)*
>   In short, I will keep on compensating and reach the perfect thing. *(lit. The point is: I will pile up compensation over compensation and reach the perfect thing, that is what it's about.)*
>   **Moreover if it's This, I will use what he had as a reference.** *(lit. If it's This, from what he had I will use it as a reference)*
>   In addition, if it's about magic power it has been flowing through my body for quite some time.
>   What's left is to keep on repeating the process.

I think it's used when people want to talk about something they know and is known with the audience but the author does not want to make it clear until some time later.
Am I right?

He is referring to a bow since he is talking about an archer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have gotten から wrong; it denotes a reason here (not "from").

> それにコレだったら、あいつが持ってたから参考になる。
>   (lit.) And as for this, because he had it, it serves as a reference.

And it appears to me that this あいつが持っていたコレ refers to something which is not directly mentioned in this excerpt. Perhaps this コレ will be described later, or it has been already described before.

Maybe he's referring to some magical device/book/etc used to fortify the bow.

Comment: Yeah, I tought it was something which was going to be defined later.
Thanks for correcting から I was slightly confused by that too.